# Adding attachment paths to a list on an asp.net page in C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to create a function that will insert multiple attachments with a work item in TFS through a webform. My initial thought was to create a list that contains the filepaths of the attachments uploaded to the webform, and then add the attachments to the work item with:

```
foreach (string attachment in attachmentList)
            {
                Task.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
            }
```

The problem is that I can't seem to populate the list.
I have tried with the code below, but the UploadButton_click function does not seem to add paths to the attachmentList and I can't figure out why.

`List<string> attachmentList = new List<string>();`

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String savePath = @"c:\temp\uploads\";

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {

            String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

            savePath += fileName;

            FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

            UploadStatusLabel.Text = fileName + " was successfully uploaded" ;

            Label1.Text +=fileName + ", ";
            attachmentList.Add(savePath);

        }
        else
        {
            UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code at all?

Comment: Yeah, still can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. The list has to be static in this case

```
static List<string> attachmentList = new List<string>();
```